# Spring Boot project: how to set the Entity class if I don't have id as primary key

Tags: spring-boot

I am creating a project in spring boot and as an example I am following an exercise on the internet where there is a primary key id and other fields. (the code is below).

When creating Entity / POJO class there is the @Id annotation which indicates that the member field below is the primary key of current entity with the addition of the @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation which is used to configure the increment of the specified column (field). And so far everything is clear.

Now a doubt arises; since the exercise I have to do does not have Id as primary key but has a code called PersonCode as primary key composed of both numeric and alphabetic characters (therefore it is not an auto-incremented field, but you have to enter it manually every time you create a new person ), what should be put in place of the @Id and @GeneratedValue annotations?
I hope I have been clear and I apologize for this question, I am a beginner.

```js
import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;  
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;  
import javax.persistence.Id;  
import javax.persistence.Table;  
  
@Entity  
@Table(name="student")  
public class Student {  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private int student_id;  
    private String student_name;  
    private String student_email;  
    
    // Get and set methods

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a manually generated value, you don't add `@GeneratedValue`. `@Id` must be used to indicate that this field represents the primary key.

Naturally, any time a `Student` is to be saved, it's `student_id` must be filled in beforehand, Spring won't generate and id for you.

Comment: since I don't have id as primary key, @Id don't put it in the code right? does something else go in its place?

Comment: Every entity needs a primary key, and the primary key is indicated with `@Id`. It doesn't matter what you call the field or the column in the database, but you must tell Spring that that column is the pk.

Comment: ok but since I have PersonCode as primary key composed of both numeric and alphabetic characters (so it is not an auto-incremented field, but you have to insert it manually every time you create a new person) how can I declare that this is pk a Spring?

Comment: By annotating it with `@Id`. This indicates that field is the primary key. It doesn't matter that it's not a number (though you'll need to change to type to `String`).

Comment: so @Id is always used to indicate the primary key? I thought it was only used to indicate the student id as the primary key. So it always applies